# silent StMoMo package messages

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using [StMoMo](https://github.com/amvillegas/StMoMo) to fit mortality models. Currently I'm working on ioslies presentation in RStudio. However, I'm not able to silent the package messages.

Here is my chunk:

````
```{r, verbose=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(StMoMo)
Dxt <- EWMaleData$Dxt
Ext <- EWMaleData$Ext + 0.5 * EWMaleData$Dxt
ages <- EWMaleData$ages
years <- EWMaleData$years
ages.fit <- 55:89
wxt <- genWeightMat(ages = ages.fit, years = years, clip = 3)
LCfit <- fit(LC, Dxt = Dxt, Ext = Ext, ages = ages, years = years,
ages.fit = ages.fit, wxt = wxt)
```
````

However I still get below info in knitr HTML output:

```
## StMoMo: The following cohorts have been zero weigthed: 1872 1873 1874     1954 1955 1956
## StMoMo: Start fitting with gnm
## Initialising
## Running start-up iterations..
## Running main iterations.....
## Done
## StMoMo: Finish fitting with gnm
```

Any ideas how to get rid of this information, but still evaluate the code?

Comment: You could try to wrap the `fit` call (and all other calls that clutter up your output) in `capture.output`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the argument `verbose = FALSE` in the `fit` function to silent StMoMo, i.e.,

```
LCfit <- fit(LC, Dxt = Dxt, Ext = Ext, ages = ages, years = years, 
         ages.fit =   ages.fit, wxt = wxt, verbose = FALSE)
```